# Sharepoint list items are not coming in the response of api call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft graph API. I made calls to get the lists of the sites and response resulted in listing all the lists available. Then used list id to fetch the items, but no items are displaying in the values field of response JSON. There are items in the list and can be seen in SharePoint. The API call made is to fetch the items - 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/abc.sharepoint.com,{SPSite.ID},{SPWeb.ID}/lists/{list-id}/items`

and it returns-

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites('abc.sharepoint.com%2C792f04d7-8a76-4ccf-95fd-10e3293536c4%2Ca422fba2-947c-44ef-8134-ddd560d6bb3d')/lists('0c739bcd-8649-4fa6-bca4-a8dcea53e2c2')/items",
    "value": []
}
```

To get the lists, which is working - 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/abc.sharepoint.com,{SPSite.ID},{SPWeb.ID}/lists/`

and displays all the available lists.

I am referring this [doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/listitem_list)  .

Using postman to make the calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use test query tool below to check if it works.

[Graph-Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#)

It works using the API below in my test.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/abc.sharepoint.com,{Site GUID},{Web GUID}/lists/{List GUID}/items
```

You can also check if the list id is right.

Comment: I just wonder, why isn't working with the postman. It's working with Graph-Explorer, thanks for the help.